# Error con textbox en VB.Net usando autocompletar

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Tengo el siguiente codigo para poder realizar un autocompletar en varios textbox que tengo en mi aplicación. Está conectado a una base de datos en otra compu que es servidor. Pero el error me da tanto de los clientes como de los servidores.

Sacando el tema de sqlinjection que sé que mi codigo es vulnerable, hay momentos donde el codigo funciona y momentos donde no.

Aclaro que la base es muy grande y la consulta que muestro es solo uno de los textbox que usaré. La info la saco de una tabla llamada empleados, y la columna es nro_doc.

Public Sub autocompletar(ByVal textbx As TextBox, ByVal tabla As String, ByVal descripcion As String) Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand Dim res As DataTable Dim sql As String = ""

```
sql &= "SELECT top 10 " & descripcion & " FROM " & tabla & " WHERE " & descripcion & " LIKE '" & textbx.Text & "%'"


If conectar() = resultado.ok Then
    Try
        If textbx.Text <> "" Then
            res = acceso.consulta(sql)
            If res.Rows.Count() <> 0 Then
                textbx.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.None
                If res.Rows.Count() <> 0 Then
                    Dim c As Integer = 0
                    For c = 0 To res.Rows.Count() - 1
                        textbx.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
                        textbx.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
                        textbx.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(res.Rows(c).ToString)
                        'textbx.AutoCompleteCustomSource = res.Item(descripcion)
                    Next
                End If
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Error al intentar conectar", "Error grave")
    Me.ultimo_error = ex.Message
End Try
End If
```

End Sub
A su vez, el metodo lo estoy llamando desde el evento del textbox ChangeText.

Private Sub txt_nro_documento_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txt_nro_documento.TextChanged acceso.autocompletar(txt_nro_documento, "EMPLEADOS", "nro_doc") End Sub

Y ahora sì, el error que me está dando es este:

system.accessviolationexception intento de leer o escribir en la memoria protegida.A menudo, esto indica que hay otra memoria dañada.

Busqué por todos lados pero no he encontrado solución que se adapte a mi problema. Pongo lo del textbox porque antes esto no pasaba y me parece que todo está originando ahí ya que cuando saco el autocompletar no hay errores.

Gracias, espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, ¡soy novata, asi que plis paciencia!

Answer (score 0):

**Sugerencias**

Cambia

```
Public Sub autocompletar(ByVal textbx As TextBox, 
      ByVal tabla As String, ByVal descripcion As String)
```

que sea

```
Public Sub autocompletar(ByRef textbx As TextBox, 
       ByVal tabla As String, ByVal descripcion As String)
```

básicamente se esta cambiando que el TextBox pase por referencia y no por valor.

Antes de

```
If conectar() = resultado.ok Then
```

realizar los cambios:

```
textbx.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.None
textbx.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None
textbx.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Clear
```

Dentro de

```
If res.Rows.Count() <> 0 Then
```

realizar

```
textbx.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
textbx.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
```

y solo dentro del `For`

```
textbx.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(res.Rows(c).ToString)
```